# Why doesn't it turn every label to red? [Java]

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm new to coding, and I've been trying to turn all my JLabels to red, but for some reason, it just doesn't work. Some of the squares still stay the same color. This is what my code looks like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Build {
    JPanel[][] rod = new JPanel[11][11];
    JLabel[][] label = new JLabel[11][11];
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
    JLabel[][] store = new JLabel[11][11];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Start");
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Build();
    }

    public Build() {

        frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setSize(330, 330);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 11));
        Random rand = new Random();
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(30, 30);
        for (int row = 0; row < label.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < label[row].length; col++) {
                JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();
                myLabel = new JLabel();
                myLabel.setOpaque(true);
                myLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                if (row % 2 == 0) {

                    myLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }

                myLabel.setPreferredSize(dimension);
                myLabel.setBorder(border);
                frame.add(myLabel);
                label[row][col] = myLabel;

            }
            int ran = rand.nextInt(11);
            label[row][ran].setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            store = label.clone();
        }

        frame.setVisible(true);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int e = scan.nextInt();
        if (e == 1) {
            store();
        }

    }

    public void store() {
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {

            for (int j = 0; j < label[i].length; j++) {
                while (label[i][j] == null) {
                    System.out.println("wow");

                }

                label[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);

                label[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is for me to have every row from 1-10 be copied from a previous row (like row 0 becomes row 1), which is why I had a store array set up, but I'm struggling to see why this code doesn't turn every square from 1-10 red.

DATA:
(before running store()):
[Works normal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23UlA.png)

(After running store()):
[The first row hasn't changed, so that's good, but it's not working well for the rest.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcaiF.png)

Comment: I formatted your code so it's easier to read and understand.  What exactly do the 11 rows of data look like?  How can anyone reproduce your problem without that information?

Comment: Hello there! Thanks! So the rows of data look different every time I run it. The code that I believe is causing the issue is in the method store().

Comment: The rows look largely red, but there are some white and black tiles that stay put. I thought I had cracked the code with the while-null statement, but it seems like nothing has changed :(. I'm stumped.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  Edit your question to put in an example of the 11 lines of data.  I have no idea what I'm supposed to type.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Okay, so I have updated the post with images. Rerunning gives me the same issue of random squares being left out, I think.

Comment: What are the actual characters or digits that a person has to type to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what that means. Does it mean where the problem is? If so, I believe the issue lies at: label[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);

Comment: You execute your program.  The Scanner starts.  A person has to type 11 rows of information for your program to do something.  What are the actual characters or digits that a user of your program has to type to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean! When you type '1', then the method store() starts. That's where the problem lies.

Comment: In your store method, change your first for statement to `for (int i = label.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) `

Comment: Alright! But random squares still seem to be randomly black and white. How can I fix that? Should I be checking to see if a label is null?

Comment: The problem is not that the `store()` method is wrong. The problem is that you are calling it from the main thread and manipulate swing objects in it. Swing is not thread safe and you should change swing objects only on the EDT. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ for more details.

Comment: Thank you! No wonder it was acting strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your code to illustrate some basic Swing principles.

Here's the GUI I came up with.  I made the random cells blue instead of white so you could see that I did, in fact, make one cell in each row a different color.  I separated the cells by 2 pixels so you can see each white cell more clearly.

[image]

Here's the GUI after you left-click the button.

[image]

As you can see, all the cells are now red.

I removed the `Scanner` console code and replaced it with a GUI `JButton`.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

The first thing you do, in the main method, is call the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that you create and execute the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a `JFrame` and two `JPanels`.  One `JPanel` holds the cells, while the other `JPanel` holds the `JButton`.  Yes, you can add Swing components directly to a `JFrame`, but it is not wise to do so.  Always create a `JPanel` to hold your Swing components and place the `JPanel` on the `JFrame`.

The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` and the two `JPanels` into separate methods.  this makes the code much easier to read and understand.

I created an `ActionListener` for the `JButton`.  This is how, In Swing, you wait for a user action.

This code should be a better base for what you're trying to accomplish.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Build implements Runnable {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Build());
    }
    
    private JLabel[][] label;
    
    private Random random;
    
    public Build() {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.label = new JLabel[11][11];
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Start");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 11, 2, 2));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(30, 30);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        for (int row = 0; row < label.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < label[row].length; col++) {
                label[row][col] = new JLabel();
                label[row][col].setBorder(border);
                label[row][col].setOpaque(true);
                label[row][col].setPreferredSize(dimension);
                
                if (row % 2 == 0) {
                    label[row][col].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    label[row][col].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }

                panel.add(label[row][col]);
            }
            
            int ran = random.nextInt(label[row].length);
            label[row][ran].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            for (int i = label.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (int j = 0; j < label[i].length; j++) {
                    label[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```